# Magnolia archetype can't resolve info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project:pom:5.3

Tags: maven, build, magnolia

I'm trying to use maven archetype to create a Magnolia project by running:

```
D:\workingFolder\workspace\MagnoliaTutorial5.3\tryProjects> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

and choose

5: http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/ -> info.magnolia.maven.archetypes:magnolia-project-archetype (An arch
etype to create a Magnolia project (a parent pom and a webapp))

and configure the properties as follow:

```
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.try.projects
artifactId: tryProjects
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.try.projects
magnolia-version: 5.3
project-name: tryProjects
```

project creation is successful but when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

I run into following problem:

```
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project

Reason: POM 'info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any reposito
ry

  info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project:pom:5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: POM 'info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project' not found in repository: Unable
to download the artifact from any repository

  info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project:pom:5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project' not found in reposit
ory: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project:pom:5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.mergeManagedDependencies(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1456)

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.processProjectLogic(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:999)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:880)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.mergeManagedDependencies(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1456)

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.processProjectLogic(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:999)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:880)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:50
8)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  info.magnolia.ui:magnolia-ui-project:pom:5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        ... 27 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jul 20 22:47:32 SGT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use earlier version 5.1.1 this problem is not occurred. looks like something wrong for the repository but I can't figure out the solution for this. 
Any ideal how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnolia's modules are located in their own maven repository, so you need to add this one to your `settings.xml`.

The following command can be executed from a terminal in your `.m2` repository (usually `<user-dir>/.m2`) and will download a `settings.xml` file preconfigured for Magnolia CE:

```
mvn org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-maven-plugin:1.9.2.4:settings-download -Dnexus.url=http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com -Dsettings.templateId=magnolia-community-public
```

You will only need to do this step once. After that, maven knows Magnolia's maven repo.

Documentation: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Maven+init

Comment: I had already done this step before I encountered the error. But I tried to regenerate setting.xml today and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Maven+setup
for CE users, you need to use the following command in .m2 folder:

```
mvn org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-m2settings-maven-plugin:1.6.5:download -DnexusUrl=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com -Dusername=anonymous -Dpassword=anonymous -DtemplateId=magnolia-community-public
```